# Issue when consuming WCF service in phonegap application

Tags: wcf, cordova, iis-7

First, I consumed WCF service in my asp.net application, everything is ok. But it does not work in my phonegap application.
Here is my detailed error message. (First two are warnings and last one is error.)
Warning 1: Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported. index.html:7
Warning 2: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type    text/html: "http://:64514/Service1.svc?wsdl/MyFunction&callback=jQuery1900010203775251284242_1364550121569&Count1&_=1364550121570".
Error 1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Service1.svc:1

Here is my code snippets.
My WCF code:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string MyFunction(string value);

    public string MyFunction(string Count)
    {
        return "The Count you passed in is: " + Count.ToString();
    }
```

My HTML code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var counter = 0;
    var varType;
    var varUrl;
    var varData;
    var varContentType;
    var varDataType;
    var varProcessData;

    function CallMyService() {
    counter++;

    varType = "POST";
    varUrl = "http://<domain>:64514/Service1.svc?wsdl/MyFunction";
    varData = "Count" + counter;
    varContentType = "application/javascript; charset=utf-8";
    varDataType = "jsonp";
    varProcessData = true;

    CallWcfService();
    return true;
    }

    function CallWcfService() {
    $.ajax({
    type: varType,
    url: varUrl,
    data: varData,
    contentType: varContentType,
    dataType: varDataType,
    crossDomain: true,
    processdata: varProcessData,
    success: function (msg) {
    ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed
    });
    }

    function ServiceFailed(result) {
    Log('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '  ' + result.statusText);
    return 0;
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    resultObject = result.MyFunctionResult;
    Log("Success: " + resultObject);
    }

    function Log(msg) {
    $("#logdiv").append(msg + "<br />");
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Execute" onclick="CallMyService();" />

    <div id="logdiv"></div> 
    </body>
```

My WCF web config file:

```
    <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Service.Service1Behavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
    <identity>
    <dns value="http://<domain>:64514/" />
    </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: Any comments here? Thanks,

Comment: Any unclear information I just provided here?